# Integrating AWS SDK as a library in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, amazon-web-services

Is there already a handy CI 2 library for AWS SDK 1.5.x? If not, what would be the steps to make it into one?

I found a 3 year old posting about integrating Tarzan (the pre-pre-cursor to AWS SDK) to CI 1 here: http://blog.myonepage.com/integrating-tarzan-amazon-web-services-php-to. I am wondering if these instructions still hold? One difference I noticed was that the way AWS SDK 1.5.3 declares its Access Identifiers has changed and I am not quite sure how to proceed to inform CI about this.

Thanks!
mmiz

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The blog post you linked is still basically valid, here's what exactly you need to do:

First put SDK into subfolder inside libraries folder (for ex. aws-sdk-for-php). This is the file awslib.php in libraries folder:

```
class Awslib {

    function Awslib()
    {
        require_once('aws-sdk-for-php/sdk.class.php');
    }
}
```

And then just use whatever AWS service you wish in the controller, let's say it's SQS:

```
    $this->load->library('awslib');
    $sqs = new AmazonSQS();
    $response = $sqs->list_queues();
    var_dump($response->isOK());
```

Don't forget to set your credentials and rename the sample config file.

Comment: I am using this and get the details by $s3 = $this->awslib->get_s3();
           $s3->disable_ssl_verification();
            $result = $s3->list_buckets();

Comment: But please tell me how to upload file, I means what is the function like $s3->list_buckets() to upload file and delete file

Answer (score 1):

Try this CodeIgniter library for amazon https://github.com/linuxjuggler/codeigniter-amazon-sdk

Comment: Sorry about the slow response - I've been tied down w/ something else. I will check out this library! Thanks.