# Codeigniter Daemon using System_Daemon package

Tags: php, codeigniter, daemon

I am trying to create a daemon using System_Daemon package with CodeIgniter's CLI. This is a new area for me and I'm struggling.

Here's what I have:
A CI controller that injects messages into an AWS SQS queue (Thanks to [url=http://codeigniter.com/forums/member/196201/]coccodrillo[/url] for providing excellent instructions on how to integrated AWS SDK into CI. See here: [Integrating AWS SDK as a library in Codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9541613/integrating-aws-sdk-as-a-library-in-codeigniter)).

A CI controller that receives messages in the queue and writes it out to a log file and then deletes the message in the queue.

I would like to have a CI daemon which will listen to this queue, receive messages when they are there and do something useful with the message and then delete the message. So I started with the example in the documentation for System_Daemon and added in the CI code from receiving program. See code below

Is this the right thing to do? Can you guide me into doing this the "right way"?  I've trolled the various knowledgeable forums and have come up short....Help me please!

Mmiz

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?php

// Make it possible to test in source directory
// This is for PEAR developers only
ini_set('include_path', ini_get('include_path').':..');

// Include Class
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require_once "System/Daemon.php";

// Bare minimum setup
System_Daemon::setOption("appName", "receiveaws");
System_Daemon::setOption("logLocation","/tmp/log/receiveaws.log");
System_Daemon::setOption("appPidLocation","/tmp/log/receiveaws/receiveaws.pid");
System_Daemon::log(System_Daemon::LOG_INFO, "Daemon not yet started so this will be written on-screen");

// Spawn Deamon!
System_Daemon::start();
System_Daemon::log(System_Daemon::LOG_INFO, "Daemon: '".
    System_Daemon::getOption("appName").
        "' spawned! This will be written to ".
            System_Daemon::getOption("logLocation"));

System_Daemon::log(System_Daemon::LOG_WARNING, 'My php code starting');
class Receiveaws extends CI_Controller {

    public function index(){
    if ($this->input->is_cli_request()) {
        //Load the aws library
        $this->load->library('awslib');
        $sqs = new AmazonSQS();

        //Get the queue to look at
        $res=$sqs->get_queue_url('example-queue');

        //Get the queue's url
        $qurl=($res->body->GetQueueUrlResult->QueueUrl);
        System_Daemon::log(System_Daemon::LOG_INFO,$qurl);

        //Get a message from the queue
        $response = $sqs->receive_message($qurl);

        //If there was a message received, then do something
            if ($res->isOK()) {
            System_Daemon::log(System_Daemon::LOG_INFO,"Receive message successful");
                            //Now delete message from queue
            $res=$sqs->delete_message($qurl,$rcpt_hand);
            if ($res->isOK()) {
                System_Daemon::log(System_Daemon::LOG_INFO,"Delete message successful");
            }
        } else {
            //go back to check for messages
            //How do you do that?
        }
    } else {
        //Access from URL - so bail out?
        //how do you not bail out of the daemon from here?
    }
    }
}
System_Daemon::stop();
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A daemon is a process running 'forever' in the background.
Here, all you do is checking for one new message in the queue, then you exit.
Basicly you have to add a loop that take all the code that need to be executed. You need to perform a sleep in the loop to, to avoid your daemon taking up all available resources.

Anyway, php isn't good at daemon because some memory is never freed until the end of the script. If your script never end (like a daemon), it'll eat up all available memory (according to php configuration) then die with an error. You will have to code you script very carefully to avoid such memory leaks!

Also, take note that each time you ask the sqs library something, it send a http request to Amazon servers. It can be very costly to do that too often.

To compensate, I recommend you to use a cronjob that run every minute to check for new task. This way you avoid memory leaks (php process goes down between executions) and too much network usage (request are made one ina  minute).

On the last note, if you don't plan on having many tasks (that means, your daemon does nothing 99% of the time), consider using a push queue instead. With a push queue, it's not your script that poll the queue anymore, but the queue notify your script (ie: call you script with a standard http request) every time some task need to be done. This avoid running the script needlessy.

I don't know if amazon provides push queues, but ironmq (another 'free' queue service) can provide them.
More information: http://dev.iron.io/mq/reference/push_queues/

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! I too have come to the conclusion that a cron job is the way to go. Thanks for the push_queues pointer as well. Much appreciated.